# Ambiguity Resolution

Tags: c++, function, object, declaration, ambiguity

```
void S(){}
struct S{};

int main(){
   S();
}
```

In the code above, the expression 'S()' in main is treated as a function call expression rather than an attempt to create a temporary of type 'S'.

Which portion of the C++ Standard talks about the resolution of such an expression in favour of a function declaration? For some reason I am unable to locate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Section 3.3.7/2**

> A class name (9.1) or enumeration name (7.2) can be hidden by the name of an object, function, or enumerator declared in the same scope.  **If a class or enumeration name and an object, function, or enumerator are
>   declared in the same scope (in any order) with the same name, the  class  or  enumeration  name  is  hidden
>   wherever the object, function, or enumerator name is visible**.

Then you need to use elaborated type specifier in such cases

**3.4.4/1  Elaborated type specifiers**

> **An elaborated-type-specifier may be used to refer to a previously declared class-name or enum-name even
>   though the name has been hidden by a non-type declaration (3.3.7).**  The class-name or enum-name in the
>   elaborated-type-specifier may either be a simple identifer or be a qualified-id.

Comment: Yup buddy. That's the one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be resolved either by using the scope resolution operator(::) or by using virtual keyword(when we are dealing with either multiple or hybrid inheritance.